# Android - PagerAdapter instantiateObject not being called

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've been pulling my hair out for a day over this - I inherited from PagerAdapter and called the following from my main Activity. 
The problem is that test below always returns `null`. 
Also, when I debug, I found that instantiateItem method in MyPagerAdapter.java was not entered at all! What gives?

Appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks.

Pier.

```
    // For the paging swipes
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

    View test = m_ViewPager.getChildAt(2);
    ListView theList = (ListView) test.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    //Log.d("Instantiate Item", null);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //View view = null; 
    View view; 

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.page1;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView txtView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ListView lstView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.page2;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView txtView2 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.page3;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView txtView3 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.page4;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView txtView4 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.page5;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView txtView5 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        break; 
    default:
        resId = R.layout.page1;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        break;
    }

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
}
```

Comment: By test fail do You mean your theList is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this line `Log.d("Instantiate Item", null);` causes an exception, because of null message.

I've tried Your adapter and it works fine (instantiateItem get called and I observe views on the phone). Seems You've tried to run your 'test' from onCreate(). You're probably expecting that ViewPager which was just inflated in setContentView() is ready to go and have child presented right after inflation. It's not true, because ViewPager would require child items only on drawing.

Comment: I think the one causing the exception is View view = null. After removing Log.d("Instantiate Item", null) it still crashes. But you're right in the sense that the offending code is here as well as running the test from onCreate. The thing is I really don't understand that this works - supposed I want to populate a ListItem on the page R.id.listView1 when the user clicks on the selection - where should I do so ?

Comment: Regarding this, is there a good ViewPager tutorial out there? The one I have been following doesn't seem to address all of the implementation.

Comment: Regarding tutorial - I know only http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html has some details. Regarding exception - you're right, first I've done was deletion of 'test.findViewById'call, but I've assumed that You've mentioned it already as test fail. Regarding question about list item population - I think listview (or viewpager etc.) is responsible for it. You can intercept it only if implement (or extend existing) view with adapter. Currently android list containers (viewpager also) populates view only then need to draw the content (afaik).

Comment: Thanks sandrstar, answer accepted, I included some code to populate a list within pageadapter in case someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

On the same note, I realised that in order to populate say, my ListView for position 0, I do it inside the PageAdapter. Trying to do this

```
    m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    if (m_ViewPager != null)
    {
    LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) m_ViewPager.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
        if (test != null)
        {
            if (tab.getPosition()==0)
            {
                ListView theList = (ListView) test.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                populateListView(theList, tab.getPosition());
            }
        }
    }
```

inside one of the functions in my MainActivity.java file doesn't really work for me. 
So basically, I needed to do this. Hope this helps someone who is stuck like me.

```
   @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view; 

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.page1;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView textView1 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ListView listView1 = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        populateListView(listView1, container.getContext());
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.page2;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView textView2 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.page3;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView textView3 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.page4;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView textView4 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.page5;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        TextView textView5 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        break; 
    default:
        resId = R.layout.page1;
        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        break;
    }


    ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

private void populateListView(ListView list, Context thisContext)
{
    // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

    // Create an array adapter for the list view, using the Ipsum headlines array
    list.setAdapter((new ArrayAdapter<String>(thisContext, layout, Ipsum.Headlines))); 
}
```